# What kind of musical instruments were used in ancient barbarian tribes?

Tags: ancient-history, europe

I am a member of a reenactment group in Romania, and we mostly do Roman, Dacian tribes and other barbarian tribes (allies of Dacians).

Some other members including myself want to form a band, and be as historically accurate as possible.

So what kind of musical instruments were used back then?

I think we have the drums covered, and kind of know how they should be (with some animal skin, for example pork).
But with other instruments, I'm completely lost on how it should look like, or if some sort of proto-guitar even existed.

But, given the influence the Romans had in those parts of the world, can we assume that they could have used Roman instruments?

Comment: Bagpipes. That's how you know they were barbarians ;)

Comment: :D True, but I tink those were used more in the anglophone parts, not the slavic part of Europe, so it's not really dacian specific. But thanks, that gave me an idea that there's a high chance that some sort of flutes were also used.
But even with that, I wouldn't know how many holes it could've had, for example.

Comment: There are plenty of results when googling ancient musical instruments history.

Comment: There are, but I found those to be really general. I was hoping someone has some expertise with this, depending on the region. I wouldn't use an instrument that was found in Asia, for example. Or even one used by Vikings.

Comment: I'd check this funny article: http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Asterix-Music.html

Comment: Wow, awesome, @Alberto, thank you. It probably isn't totally accurate, but a good starting point for further research.

Comment: @AlexGrigore - I had a friend go visit Bulgaria and come back with a souvenir depicting people in traditional dress (shockingly) playing bagpipes. Turns out they are actually a traditional instrument all over Europe, going back at least as far as the middle ages.

Comment: Bagpipes were used all over; they were invented long before the Scots wore plaid kilts:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagpipes#Ancient_origins

Comment: @AlexGrigore - No short answer but an idea for research, you could use Google search on [**Prehistoric Dacia**](http://www.prehistoricdacia.info). For instance, there's  "**[flute (aulon)](http://www.prehistoricdacia.info/website4/27_01.htm)**" and "**[flute (tibia) and the tympani](http://www.prehistoricdacia.info/website5/33_24.htm)**"